# OR LIKE sql query boolean error

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to search an employee record but i'm getting this error message:

```
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'OR'.
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
sConn = new SqlConnection(sStr);

daEmp2 = new SqlDataAdapter("
SELECT employee.*,
       department.Department
FROM tblEmployee employee
INNER JOIN tblDepartment department ON employee.DeptID=department.DeptID
WHERE Lname OR Fname LIKE '%" + txtName.Text + "%'
", sConn);

dsEmp2 = new DataSet();
daEmp2.Fill(dsEmp2, "tblEmployee");
```

is there something wrong with my query?

Comment: Warning: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection Attacks.  Do not simply concatenate strings to form SQL Statements.  Instead, use parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query contains a syntactical error because you don't provide an operator and a comparison value for the `Lname` field

```
...  where Lname ??????? OR Fname LIKE ...
```

After the `Lname` you should add an operator (=, LIKE...) and a comparison value to allow the evaluation of the expression

```
...  where Lname LIKE 'AName' OR Fname LIKE ...
```

Apart from this, please remove the string concatenation used for the FName value and use a parameterized query

For example

```
 using(sConn = new SqlConnection(sStr))
 using(daEmp2 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT employee.*,department.Department " + 
                            "FROM tblEmployee employee inner join tblDepartment department " + 
                            "on employee.DeptID=department.DeptID " + 
                            "where Lname LIKE @last OR Fname LIKE @first", sConn))
 {
      daEmp2.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last", "%" + LastNameTextBox.Text + "%");
      daEmp2.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first", "%" + txtName.Text  + "%");
      dsEmp2 = new DataSet();
      daEmp2.Fill(dsEmp2, "tblEmployee");
 }
```

Using a parameterized query avoid the possibility of Sql Injection, a security problem really easy to leverage as you can see from this [very famous comic strip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)

Answer (score 4):

`or` connects boolean conditions in SQL -- conditions that evaluate to true or false.

You need to repeat the condition:

```
Lname LIKE '%" + txtName.Text + "%'" OR Fname LIKE '%" + txtName.Text + "%'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use twice LIKE expression:

```
"SELECT .....  WHERE Lname LIKE '%" + txtName.Text + "%' OR Fname LIKE '%" + txtName.Text + "%'"
```